# In react router is onEnter is same as onLeave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In react router [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onleaveprevstate) for `onEnter` hook they specified how to handle but for `onLeave` there is no example. My question is how to confirm that user want to leave page properly.

According to code given below in both cases whether user click on `cancel` or `ok` it leaves the page. However onEnter hook working fine as per logic.

```
const checkEnterAbout = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    if(!confirm('do you want to enter really!!!')){
        replace(`/`);
    }else{
        callback();
    }

}

const checkLeaveAbout = (prevState) => {
    console.log(prevState);
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page");
}

<Route path="/about"  component={About} onEnter={checkEnterAbout} onLeave={checkLeaveAbout} />
```

Also when I tried [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md) confirming guide.  its giving me an error of

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`.
    in Route
```

Comment: Do you want a confirmation on **any** page the user leaves? Or just the about page?

Comment: just about page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a hook called `routerWillLeave`, here's an example:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md

Comment: after changing export default withRouter(About) to module.exports = withRouter(About); it is working. wondering why onLeave and onEnter api interface is not same. one is working through componentDidMount and other is via using onEnter !!!